# Problems with serial port read/write in Matlab

Tags: matlab, serial-port

I have a CyberGlove connected to Matlab via serial port. I am trying to write a command requesting a data sample, and then reading the sample back.

I have successfully connected the glove with the following code:

```
s = serial('/dev/ttyS0')
set(s,'BaudRate',115200)
fopen(s)
```

I can then write/read to get the sensor information either in binary or ascii.

In binary I am doing:

```
fwrite(s,'G')
fread(s)
```

`fread` always times out and then spits out a column vector of seemingly random length (1-100+) containing meaningless integers.

With ASCII, the commands are:

```
fprintf(s,'g')
fscanf(s)
```

This gives an empty string as the read-out value.  I know that the glove is getting and at least somewhat processing the commands, though, because if I give it an invalid command, I get back the error message `e?`.

Here's the part that really confuses me, though: I accidentally discovered a way to get a correct reading from the glove.

`fread(s)` (which times out and gives the seemingly random output)

`fprintf(s,'g')`

`fscanf(s)`

I then get the string output `'g 1 76 93 113 89 42 20 77 98 106 117 81 62 23 52 60 34 68 57 254 92 26'`, which is correct.

My questions are:

(1) Why does that last part produce a correct response?

(2) How can I get a reading from the binary command?  This is what I actually want to acquire.

Comment: This sounds like its more a problem with the communication protocol of the device and not a Matlab problem.

Comment: So, it seems I should probably test it in something else, then?  Is there a simple command line method I could use for this?

Comment: Good question... Not sure whether this is the best way, but I guess you could use `cat /dev/ttyS0` for reading  and `printf ... > /dev/ttyS0` for writing. printf is a bash built-in. But first thing I'd recommend is to check the documentation of the device and see whether you understand everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the problem:
The timeout was occurring because it wasn't getting back as many bytes as it expected, and it was expecting the incorrect number.  By default, `get(s, 'InputBufferSize')` returned 512, while the actual data was 24 bytes.  Before calling `fopen(s)`, I just ran `set(s, 'InputBufferSize', 24);` and got the correct 24 8-bit integers from the binary read/write that I was expecting, without a timeout.